# What is the best test for comparing two means of unknown size and standard deviation?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test, mean

I need to compare a series of means for two unequal student groups (A & B) and need help identifying which test is best to use.  I do **not** have access to the entire data set, just summary information.  How do I calculate if there is a significant difference in the number of students in each group in the table below (e.g. Hispanic students). Is this even possible with the data available?

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You seem to *have* the number of students in different categories. What do you need a test for?

Comment: I need to test if there is any significant difference between the individuals in group A vs. group B by category.  For example, are there significantly more females (as a proportion of school size) at School A than School B?

Comment: You don't have means. You have counts. The test to compare two proportions would be a z-test of difference in proportions (or a chi-squared test, in a different guise). You have the counts, so just input them into your favorite software & go.